# jquery concatenation issue in twitter share

Tags: javascript

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

```
                        jQuery('#twitter_share').on('click',function (e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            //share image
                            var share_image = jQuery('#share_image').val();    

                            var share_image_link = "http://<?php echo $base_url;?>?photo=" +share_image;

                            //alert(share_image_link);                          
                            //tweet content
                            //var tw_text = "Lorem Ipsum @Monkeypig Ipsum has been the industry's standard http://<?php echo $base_url;?>?photo=" +share_image;

                            var tw_text = "Lorem Ipsum @Monkeypig Ipsum has been the industry standard <a href=' + share_image_link +  '> + share_image_link + </a>"; 

                            //alert(tw_text);
                            //'<p>page , <a href="http://www.myaddress.com/' + pageno + '">link</a> </p>'

                            //tweet link
                            var twtLink = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" +tw_text;

                            //open new window
                            window.open(twtLink);
                        });
                    });
```

I want to share some content with link in twitter.But i am faceing some concatenation issue here
var tw_text = "Lorem Ipsum @Monkeypig Ipsum has been the industry standard  + share_image_link + "; 
Where i am doing wrong.I need help.

Comment: You need to use double quotes as well around `+ share_image_link +`

Answer (score 0):

You did face a string delimiter issue. Here's a model :

```
myVar='variable';
alert("here's a string and then the content of a " + myVar + ".");
```

So in your case :

```
var tw_text = "Lorem Ipsum @Monkeypig Ipsum has been the industry standard <a href=' + share_image_link +  '> + share_image_link + </a>";
```

Should be :

```
var tw_text = "Lorem Ipsum @Monkeypig Ipsum has been the industry standard <a href='" + share_image_link +  "'>" + share_image_link + "</a>";
```

Look carefully, with a highlight syntax editor such as notepad++ to understand how this is working in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

`var tw_text = "Lorem Ipsum @Monkeypig Ipsum has been the industry standard <a href=" + share_image_link +  '>' + share_image_link + "</a>";`